# Getting positions from a list of lists

Tags: haskell, sudoku

Rellevant types:

```
Data Sudoku = Sudoku [[Maybe Int]]
type Block = [Maybe Int]
rows :: Sudoku -> [[Maybe Int]]
rows (Sudoku rs) = rs
```

I have a list of lists, [[Maybe Int]], and i've stated

```
type Block = [Maybe Int]
```

The assignment i am working on is creating a Sudoku Solver, so i'd need a function to return the position of a 'blank' cell, blank being Nothing. 
The actual layout of the Sudoku would be

```
Sudoku [
        , list1
        , list2
        ....    ]
```

until i have nine lists, each containing nine elements, Nothing or Just Int.

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
```

The first Int in Pos should indicate which 'row' contains the blank cell. The second one should indicate which Element whithin that Row is the blank one. 
I've written

```
whichRow :: Sudoku -> Int
whichRow (Sudoku (x:xs)) =
    if isNothingPresent x == False then 1 + whichRow (Sudoku xs) else 1

whereIsNothing :: Block -> Int
whereIsNothing (x:xs) = if x == Nothing then 1 else 1 + whereIsNothing xs

isNothingPresent :: Block -> Bool
isNothingPresent b
    | Nothing `notElem` b = False
    | otherwise           = True
```

Now i need to combine these functions and create a function blank which will examine a Sudoku and return the position of a blank cell. I played around and tried:

```
blank :: Sudoku -> Pos 
blank sud = do k <- (whichRow sud)
               n <- (whereIsNothing (head (drop (k-1) (rows sud))))
               (return (k, n))
```

Which is obviously wrong, i get type errors and all kinds of stuff. And it looks wierd with a do block there aswell. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

I get these errors:

```
Sudoku.hs:159:22:
    Couldn't match expected type `(Int, Int)' with actual type `Int'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: k <- (whichRow sud)
    In the expression:
      do { k <- (whichRow sud);
           n <- (whereIsNothing (head (drop (k - 1) (rows sud))));
           (return (k, n)) }

Sudoku.hs:160:22:
    Couldn't match expected type `(Int, t0)' with actual type `Int'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      n <- (whereIsNothing (head (drop (k - 1) (rows sud))))
    In the expression:
      do { k <- (whichRow sud);
           n <- (whereIsNothing (head (drop (k - 1) (rows sud))));
           (return (k, n)) }

Sudoku.hs:161:24:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `(Int, t0)'
    Relevant bindings include n :: t0 (bound at Sudoku.hs:160:16)
    In the first argument of `return', namely `(k, n)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: (return (k, n))
    In the expression:
      do { k <- (whichRow sud);
           n <- (whereIsNothing (head (drop (k - 1) (rows sud))));
           (return (k, n)) }
```

edit again: Also i am pretty sure this function will behave funny if there are no blank cells..

Comment: "Which is obviously wrong, i get type errors and all kinds of stuff".  Why is it obviously wrong?  What type errors do you get?

Comment: Updated post with the errors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First*, use tail-recursive, but not recursive functions.

```
whichRow :: Sudoku -> Int
whichRow s = whichRow' s 0   -- tail-recursive
  where
    whichRow' (Sudoku (x:xs)) i = if isNothingPresent x 
        then 1 
        else whichRow' (Sudoku xs) (i+1)
```

*Second*, don't forget to look at all cases at pattern matching:

```
whichRow :: Sudoku -> Int
whichRow s = whichRow' s 0
  where
    whichRow' (Sudoku [])     i = i     -- missing case
    whichRow' (Sudoku (x:xs)) i = if isNothingPresent x 
        then 1 
        else whichRow' (Sudoku xs) (i+1)
```

*Third*, why do you use so many parentheses?

```
blank :: Sudoku -> Pos 
blank sud = do k <- whichRow sud
               n <- whereIsNothing (head (drop (k-1) (rows sud)))
               return (k, n)
```

But **MAIN** - this code is invalid. `do` is a monad, but you use `Int` only. Use `let` instead

```
blank :: Sudoku -> Pos 
blank sud = let k = whichRow sud in
            let n = whereIsNothing $ head $ drop (k-1) (rows sud) in
            (k, n)
```

or `where`

```
blank :: Sudoku -> Pos 
blank sud = (k, n)
  where
    k = whichRow sud
    n = whereIsNothing $ head $ drop (k-1) (rows sud)
```

*Fourth*, don't reuse a lot of `Bool`, like `if smth == True then ....`, write instead `if smth then ...`. Let's look at

```
isNothingPresent :: Block -> Bool
isNothingPresent b
    | Nothing `notElem` b = False
    | otherwise           = True
```

we could rewrite it to

```
isNothingPresent :: Block -> Bool
isNothingPresent b = not $ Nothing `notElem` b
```

or, more simply

```
isNothingPresent :: Block -> Bool
isNothingPresent b = Nothing `elem` b
```

Comment: ... and ``not $ a `notElem` b == a `elem` b``.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for confirmation. At first, I wrote `Nothing 'elem' b`, but I was not sure about that )))

Comment: or, `isNothingPresent = elem Nothing`